# Build an array from a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Could someone please let me know how I can create an array from the MySQL query?

**The array should look like this:**

```
<?php
$testLocs = array(
    '1' => array( 'info' => '1. New Random info and new position', 'lat' => 45345345, 'lng' => 44.9634 ),
    '2' => array( 'ino'  => '1. New Random info and new position', 'lat' => 686788787, 'lng' => 188.9634),
    '3' => array( 'info' => '1. New Random info and new position', 'lat' => 88888, 'lng' => 144.9634),
    '4' => array( 'info' => '1. New Random info and new position', 'lat' => 666666, 'lng' => 144.964 )
);
echo json_encode($testLocs);
exit();
?>
```

Where the **text** for `info` and **numbers** for `lat` and `lng` are MySQL `$rows`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Example taken from PHP manual

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I undestand it correctly you need to map mysql array results to some kind of normalized array. Function `array_map` would be perfect for it:

```
$array = array_map(function ($row) {
    return array(
        'info'  => $row['info'],
        'lat'   => $row['lat'],
        'lng'   => $row['lng'],
    );
}, $rows);
```

If you need indexes starting from 1 you should also add this line:

```
$array = array_combine(range(1, count($array)), $array);
```

Comment: could you please let me know how you would actually use this in a sql query?

Comment: I thought you already have results of mysql query. How do you connect to db from php?

Comment: I actually do have the results of mysql query. but when I place your code in my `while loop` in MYSQL query, I only get `[]` printed on my php page. that is why i asked you to show me an example if possible so I know how `array_combine` works in relation to while loop etc.

Comment: If you mean that your loop is over mysql results than it is not needed here. Function `array_map` will act like a loop and iterate over each row of results.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $testLocs = array();

   $sql = <<<SQL
            SELECT id, info, position, lat, lng
            FROM tbl_info
SQL;

    $q = mysql_query($sql);    

    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $testLocs[$r['id']] = $r;
    }

    print_r($testLocs);
```

Obviously replace the query with the correct one.

PS. This is the mysql way, not the mysqli way. It might be worth looking at both.

Comment: aren't you suppose to declare $testLocs somewhere?

Comment: Yes by rights you are. this will still work but will throw warnings. I will edit

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are **deprecated**. please consider using `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: This will print out something like this: `{"1":{"id":"1","name":"Rooz","lat":"51.5033630","lng":"-0.1276250"}}` but I need it to be like this: `{"1":{"info":"Rooz","lat":51.503363,"lng":-0.127625}}`

Comment: Yep, change query accordingly to achieve desired array, mine was a only an example

Comment: its not the query that I am concerned about! its actually the fact that it prints out the id, name etc...

Comment: I mean it prints out the columns name as well as their values.